# Hide/show content inside form generated by Ipresso

Tags: javascript, php, css, iframe

On the website I have form which is generated from ipresso. I'd like to style agreement to hide this content and after click I'd like to show it. But where I can find names of classes, id etc.? I'd like to add button "hide/show" which will hide or show content inside form.]

Comment: Have you looked into using jQuery and its hide/show functions?

Comment: Yes, it's not a problem. Problem for me is that I don't know how elements inside this form are called. As it is generated automatically on the ipresso.com. I obtained form but I'd like to give it new options like hide and show content.

Answer (score 0):

In browser on the page generated by ipresso right-click on an element that you would like to change and select option Inspect-Element/Inspect. In the source code your form should have an id/class which you then would use in jQuery as selectors, in a way that I describe below.

```
$("#toggle-button").click(function(){
    $("your-form").toggle();
});
```

OR

```
$("#hide-button").click(function(){
    $("your-form").hide();
});

$("#show-button").click(function(){
    $("your-form").show();
});
```

If the elements are always generated with different ids/classes on every refresh (I highly doubt that) another thing to do is to use more descriptive css selectors which rely on the structure of the html tags staying consistent. Again, you will be able to find them using the Inspect/Inspect-element found in most browsers. It is a workaround, but not something I would recommend doing since if the structure changes, you will have to edit in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem using jQuery toggle class just add jquery to your website if not present

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#target_div").toggle();
});
```

based on your requirement set the initial css for the div to `display:none` if it is to be hidden initially.